# Is it safe to call FragmentManager.popBackStack when activity is paused

Tags: android

Documentation of [FragmentManager.popBackStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(java.lang.String,%20int)) mentions that

> This function is asynchronous -- it enqueues the request to pop, but the action will not be performed until the application returns to its event loop.

Does this mean this can be called when the activity is paused ? Does the actual removing of fragment happens after the activity is resumed again ?

Comment: You mean you want to popBackStack inside the onPause method?

Comment: Yes inside the onPause method.

Comment: The answer is no - as I have an app that is used by roughly 2000 users per day and I am getting 2 - 3 crashes daily because I am calling popBackStack in onPaused(). You will get this exception: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"  I'd love to know why though.