# How to call FragmentManager.popBackStack when activity is paused?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onpause, fragment-backstack

I have following situation

Let's take an example:

I have FirstActivity which contains Two fragments. Fragment-A is by default loaded to FirstActivity.By clicking on a button in Fragment-A screen moves to Fragment-B and it will add to back stack.From Fragment-B there is a button from where i visit to second activity. Now if any event occurs i am calling *FragmentManager.popBackStack* method to move Fragment-B to Fragment-A(This is application requirement) at that time my application get crashed. Because i am on SecondActivity and *FragmentManager.popBackStack* call from FirstActivity.

Now my code

**When moving from Fragment-A to Fragment-B**

```
 MenuFragment menuFragment = MenuFragment.newInstance(orderObject.getOrderTableName(), orderObject.getTableSize(), arraySeatCount[k], arrayTableCode[k], arrayTableId[k], floorDetailObject.getId(), TabRabbitConstant.OrderType.DINEIN.orderType, "", "", false);
                            menuFragment.setTargetFragment(FloorFragment.this, UserDefault.ORDER_MENU);
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                                       fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameContainer, menuFragment, getResources().getString(R.string.M_MENU));
                            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(getResources().getString(R.string.M_MENU));
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**When any event occur i am calling popbackstack on FirstActivity**

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                                manager.popBackStack();
```

**Exception i get when my application getting crash is**

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1842)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1860)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStack(FragmentManager.java:770)
                                                                          at com.app.tabrabbitpos.MainActivity.parseResponseInMain(MainActivity.java:691)
                                                                          at com.app.tabrabbitpos.base.BaseActivity$3.run(BaseActivity.java:192)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Documentation of [FragmentManager.popBackStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(java.lang.String,%20int)) wrote that

**This function is asynchronous -- it enqueues the request to pop, but the action will not be performed until the application returns to its event loop.**

So according to documentation i thought it should work but it gives me exception and my application get crashed.

I have already checked this link for my issue but not getting any solution

[Is it safe to call FragmentManager.popBackStack when activity is paused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986375/is-it-safe-to-call-fragmentmanager-popbackstack-when-activity-is-paused)

**In short my question is**
*How to call FragmentManager.popBackStack when activity is paused? (Means when i am on second activity and FirstActivity is on Pause)*

Comment: Finish the second activity first when event occurs then call FragmentManager.popBackStack because when second activity is finished first activity onresume gets called.

Comment: @Anonymous actually issue is i have to finish secondactivity and call popbackstack on same time whenever i get events..so it works on same time so it is generating same issue...any other way?

Comment: you can try creating a new fragment instead of secondactivity if it is possible.that would solve your problem easily.

Comment: No friend i really need that second activity ..it is  good solution..but i can’t use it

Comment: Can I ask why you need second activity?

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean to check if activity is running for the first time like this

private Boolean mFirstRun=false;

Then in first activity onResume check if the activity is running for the first time and perform the action.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!mFirstRun){
        mFirstRun=true;
    }else {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.popBackStack();
        mFirstRun=false;
    }
}
```

When the event is fired in second activity dont forget call `finish()` in second activity which will resume the first activity again.

Comment: Let me check than i will inform you